# error pulling image configuration when apply ./get-docker-images.sh

Tags: linux, windows, docker, blockchain

```
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:amd64-0.4.13
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb/manifests/amd64-0.4.13: read tcp 10.0.2.15:47240->54.175.43.85:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

**when apply :**
 vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/bin$ **./get-docker-images.sh**

i am using VM virtual tool box with Ubuntu 16.04  on windows 8

any one have idea how to solve the problem ?

**Content of get-docker-images.sh:**

```
# set the default Docker namespace and tag
DOCKER_NS=hyperledger
ARCH=amd64
VERSION=1.3.0
BASE_DOCKER_TAG=amd64-0.4.13

# set of Hyperledger Fabric images
FABRIC_IMAGES=(fabric-peer fabric-orderer fabric-ccenv fabric-tools)

for image in ${FABRIC_IMAGES[@]}; do
  echo "Pulling ${DOCKER_NS}/$image:${ARCH}-${VERSION}"
  docker pull ${DOCKER_NS}/$image:${ARCH}-${VERSION}
done

THIRDPARTY_IMAGES=(fabric-kafka fabric-zookeeper fabric-couchdb fabric-baseos)

for image in ${THIRDPARTY_IMAGES[@]}; do
  echo "Pulling ${DOCKER_NS}/$image:${BASE_DOCKER_TAG}"
  docker pull ${DOCKER_NS}/$image:${BASE_DOCKER_TAG}
done
```

**The executed command :**

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/bin$ ./get-docker-images.sh
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.3.0
amd64-1.3.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-peer
Digest: sha256:c521647ccedf6e02a737e20ee66d6957293c8d85c2f272bf7b62fae1e2be81a5
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.3.0
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-orderer:amd64-1.3.0
amd64-1.3.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-orderer
Digest: sha256:510e0baa4d5df084f7e1de8072f2be6f0db766d668a8932b3eef19c3e9d65399
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:amd64-1.3.0
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.3.0
amd64-1.3.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
Digest: sha256:ea988663d2af2e392d686524f2d7a7ab70ee4ee783c50792b5bc9745450d776d
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:amd64-1.3.0
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-tools:amd64-1.3.0
amd64-1.3.0: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-tools
Digest: sha256:638a53bba0582adf71c08ba3658b5d05d79f49c44f38344cca7ede10dbab3290
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-tools:amd64-1.3.0
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-kafka:amd64-0.4.13
amd64-0.4.13: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-kafka
Digest: sha256:892f3ce913ea826d842bbe7e1babecf9194e873168d563c23668866d2fd29600
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-kafka:amd64-0.4.13
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:amd64-0.4.13
amd64-0.4.13: Pulling from hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
Digest: sha256:f2c0d4a4d73614e34e0161929d7571a72bc379034c704eb170c80b7acde97d92
Status: Image is up to date for hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper:amd64-0.4.13
Pulling hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:amd64-0.4.13
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb/manifests/amd64-0.4.13: read tcp 10.0.2.15:47024->54.175.43.85:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: This sounds like a network connectivity issue, or possibly a local proxy setup issue.  On its own, that's not an error message that really points to any specific problem or reproducible workaround.

Comment: but i dot have any proxy on my machine, and i can ping the site from VM Tool Box  (ping production.cloudflare.docker.com  is replying with success)

Comment: *＋1* for asking a Docker question that has to do with programming and development. You show a script with flow control.

Comment: i am just executing this command :                       vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/bin$ ./get-docker-images.sh

Comment: i found the solution :
change the DNS setup of the VM 
pointing to the Google DNS

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8   8.8.4.4

Then 
vagrant halt
vagrant up

but we need to in different timing with 
good internet speed

Comment: Open your /etc/network/interfaces file  by this command :                           sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces   and  ... pointing to the Google DNS

Comment: refer to this link for more info :   https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611

Answer (score 0):

**i found the solution :**
change the DNS setup of the VM 
pointing to the Google DNS

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8       8.8.4.4
```

Then

```
vagrant halt

vagrant up
```

**but we need to try in different timing with 
good internet speed**

Open your **/etc/network/interfaces** file by this command :                           `sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`
and  ... pointing to the Google DNS

the interfaces file should be like below :

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # The primary network interface
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up sleep 2

    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8   8.8.4.4
```

See this Link also : 
**https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/611**